# CSS display:inline have no effect

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<!-- MENU -->
        <nav id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Categories 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"<Categories 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font: 12px 'DroidSansBold', Tahoma,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
} 

#menu li{
  display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 120px;
}

#menu li ul li{
  display: none;
}

#menu li a:hover{
  color: #dc692e;
}
```

The result looks like this:[image]

I can't seem to figure out why my two categories won't accept css `display: inline`. I have an menu under each of the categories that currently is not displayed. When I remove the 'under-menu', `display:inline` works.

Not working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LynwV/

Thank for all help!

Comment: You can't have a `<nav>` as a `<li>`'s direct parent. It is invalid.

Comment: @Zenith Change it to div, and keeping the same ID should make it valid. But what exactly do you mean by invalid? It will work? I'm interested to hear your explanation :)

Comment: @claustrofob Thank you. That was it, but judging by other comments I should change my markup a bit.

Comment: @Nilzone- Some things may work, but it isn't valid markup. Check out the W3C standards + W3C validator. Changing it to a div won't make it valid, the only direct parents <li> elements can have are UL, OL or MENU elements - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@claustrofob is right, `inline-block` is the solution. However, @Zenith is also correct. You need to fix your markup. I would also change how your writing your styles, instead of long element selector chains, put a class on the element you want to target and style it that way.

Comment: I will change my markup. And @claustrofob was right indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Your a tag is wrong. `<li><a href="#"<Categories 2</a>` should be `<li><a href="#">Categories 2</a>`.
And, as @Zenith said, you can't have a nav followed directly by a LI element.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You have invalid markup, as pointed out by @Zenith, and some broken syntax as pointed out by @Josefffs

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/LynwV/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: There you go buddy i fixed you

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is, you have wrapped the list defined by `<ul>` tags by an another `<li>` tag which seems to hide the list of items.

Try the inspect element for support as well.